# Android How to capture two consecutive frames from camera

Tags: android

I'm trying to program Optical flow on android device. 
My problem is to get two consecutive frames from camera.

That's the code to get ONE frame.

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            synchronized (SampleViewBase.this) {
                mFrame2 = data;
                SampleViewBase.this.notify();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You wil have to do it like they do video recording..

Comment: Yes I use OpenCV and I'm following the tutorial 3 for native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you then do something like:

```
private byte[] currFrame;
private byte[] prevFrame;    

private void copyFrame(byte[] a){
        if(a != null) prevFrame = a;
}

mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                synchronized (SampleViewBase.this) {
                    copyFrame(currFrame);              
                    currFrame = data;
                    SampleViewBase.this.notify();
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm not sure that's proper Java syntax but just copy the `currentFrame`, before assigning `data` to it. Anyway, I think you can also use the `VideoCapture` class to obtain the frames already in a `Mat` format. I'm not sure if this class is still available in the latest release, but from my experience with Opencv 2.3 it was much faster to use it to grab camera frames than to use the Android camera.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work…the program hangs and I have to terminate it

Comment: As I was saying, I'm not sure that's proper Java coding, but it is a way of doing it. ;)

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I haven't checked the null pointer exception at the first iteration!