# Taking two frames from camera preview

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I trying to get two frames from the camera preview for comparing two pictures each time ( I am programming a motion detector)

- if I use the `setOneShotPreviewCallback()` it returns only one frame
- if I use the `setPreviewCallback()` it return a lot of frames and I cannot stop it from doing it.

I want to get exactly two frames each time.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638650/android-how-to-capture-two-consecutive-frames-from-camera ??

Comment: Idea: Try setting buffer of some size to the preview callback and compare each buffer you get through the callback. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#addCallbackBuffer(byte[])

Comment: luanjot - thanks for the link. One thing I don't understand: if I want to compare between those two frames, I need to do it before the notify() command?